# How to compare each line of a text file with a statement?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a text file of links and garbage which look like this:

```
www.facebook.com
www.google.com
123
fewfwfqwfq
```

Let's do a `for` loop and compare each line and if there is **not** a `".com"` in the specific line, the line gets deleted. In that case `'123'` and `'fewfwfqwfq'` gets deleted.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You could use `re` for this. or you could also use the string method `endswith()`

Comment: Regex is overkill for this.

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? Is it reading the file? Is it finding the "bad" lines? Is it writing the file back? Please read about [ask] and be more specific. It is also best to post a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

```
good_lines = [l for l in links if '.com' in l]

with open('fname.txt') as fout:
    [fout.write(g) for g in goodlines]
```

Comment: I think you forgot the OP wants to delete the text from the file too